# Deadlock issue in MYSQL innodb

Tags: php, select, insert, innodb, deadlock

I am facing a deadlock issue while trying to select the balance from the last row in a table and add balance + 1 and try to insert it in the same table but on high load, the deadlock issue occurs.

Below is the GitHub link https://github.com/bhatakeed/deadlock/

INNODB STATUS:

```
 ------------------------
    LATEST DETECTED DEADLOCK
    ------------------------
    2021-08-26 22:28:46 0x6f98
    *** (1) TRANSACTION:
    TRANSACTION 1580726, ACTIVE 0 sec inserting
    mysql tables in use 1, locked 1
    LOCK WAIT 6 lock struct(s), heap size 1128, 4 row lock(s)
    MySQL thread id 436, OS thread handle 24936, query id 2556 localhost 127.0.0.1 root Update
    INSERT INTO `balance` (`bal`) VALUE ('21')
    *** (1) WAITING FOR THIS LOCK TO BE GRANTED:
    RECORD LOCKS space id 1337 page no 3 n bits 80 index PRIMARY of table `test`.`balance` trx id 1580726 lock_mode X insert intention waiting
    Record lock, heap no 1 PHYSICAL RECORD: n_fields 1; compact format; info bits 0
     0: len 8; hex 73757072656d756d; asc supremum;;
    
    *** (2) TRANSACTION:
    TRANSACTION 1580729, ACTIVE 0 sec inserting
    mysql tables in use 1, locked 1
    4 lock struct(s), heap size 1128, 3 row lock(s)
    MySQL thread id 437, OS thread handle 28568, query id 2560 localhost 127.0.0.1 root Update
    INSERT INTO `balance` (`bal`) VALUE ('21')
    *** (2) HOLDS THE LOCK(S):
    RECORD LOCKS space id 1337 page no 3 n bits 80 index PRIMARY of table `test`.`balance` trx id 1580729 lock mode S
    Record lock, heap no 1 PHYSICAL RECORD: n_fields 1; compact format; info bits 0
     0: len 8; hex 73757072656d756d; asc supremum;;
    
    Record lock, heap no 12 PHYSICAL RECORD: n_fields 5; compact format; info bits 0
     0: len 4; hex 8000000f; asc     ;;
     1: len 6; hex 000000181eb3; asc       ;;
     2: len 7; hex 930000101001d7; asc        ;;
     3: len 4; hex 80000014; asc     ;;
     4: len 4; hex 6127c846; asc a' F;;
    
    *** (2) WAITING FOR THIS LOCK TO BE GRANTED:
    RECORD LOCKS space id 1337 page no 3 n bits 80 index PRIMARY of table `test`.`balance` trx id 1580729 lock_mode X insert intention waiting
    Record lock, heap no 1 PHYSICAL RECORD: n_fields 1; compact format; info bits 0
     0: len 8; hex 73757072656d756d; asc supremum;;
    
    *** WE ROLL BACK TRANSACTION (2)
    ------------
```

Thank you,

Answer (score 0):

There is no "last row" of a table.  Tables are unordered by definition.  Instead, you must use some column, usually the `PRIMARY KEY`, to identify which row you want to `SELECT` or `UPDATE`.

Once we agree on what you are doing, and get the appropriate SQL code to do it, I think the deadlock will go away.

Is this what you are talking about?

```
CREATE TABLE `balance` (
  `id` int(1) AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL,
  `bal` int(111) NOT NULL,
  `dt` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT current_timestamp(),
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`);
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

start transaction;
SELECT bal INTO @bal FROM test.test 
    ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1 LOCK IN SHARE MODE;
INSERT INTO test.test(bal,et)VALUE(@bal+1,1);
commit;
```

What is `et`?

Anyway, once you have the `id` for the row you want to change (such as `@id`), simply do

```
UPDATE bal SET bal = bal + 1;
```

There is no need to fetch the `bal` separately (unless you need it for subsequent use).  And the timestamp has a default that seems reasonable.  However, you may want to change it to get it to automatically update -- depending on whether it refers to the time when the row was *created* or the time when it was *last updated*.

In the future, please put the necessary code in the Question *as text*, not in Git or elsewhere.